# Strip characters, Including spaces, for tel: link

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a proper 'tel:' link for phone numbers that are added in an ACF text field. So I'm just trying to strip extraneous characters, but the spaces are causing a problem.

**Existing code:**

```
$html .= '<p itemprop="telephone" class="member-phone tel">
<a href="tel:+1'.preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",esc_url( $member_phone )).'">'.esc_attr( $member_phone ).'</a></p>';
```

The result of this is:

**Phone number added:** (323) 555-1212

**Resulting tel link:** +1323205551212

So I'm guessing the space is interpreted as '%20', then the percentage character is stripped, leaving the extra '20'.

- How do I modify to strip the space properly (and/or the resulting %20)?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just changing: `esc_url( $member_phone )`   to   `esc_attr( $member_phone )`

Not sure of any drawbacks to this, but it does work as the space is not interpreted as '%20'.

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in `hrefs` unencoded, but they are allowed in attributes. `esc_url()` should be used. See my answer for the proper way to escape a phone number. All this other stuff with stripping characters should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to escape a phone number link, just using `esc_url()` with the `tel:` included should be sufficient:

```
esc_url( 'tel:' . $member_phone );
```

Comment: "Defaults to return value of wp_allowed_protocols()" ... "Defaults to an array containing 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn', **'tel'**, 'fax', 'xmpp', 'webcal', and 'urn'."

Comment: I tried this implementation, but the resulting tel link was actually worse. It was output as: `<a href="tel:+1(323)%20555-1212">`

Comment: Which is valid isn’t it. What’s the probem?

Comment: While I'm assuming the parenthesis ( ) and hyphens - are not a problem, the '%20' is not part of the phone number and would cause the wrong number to be dialed.

Comment: No it won’t. The browser knows it’s an encoded space.

Comment: I see. This answer does appear to technically work, then. I'll probably stick with my solution for this, however, as the final output is a bit cleaner. The preg_replace is stripping everything but numbers, which includes spaces.

Comment: It’s hidden in an href and will be unescaped when the phone dials the number. You’re just making your code unnecessarily complex for the aesthetics of something that you can’t see.